# Extract max values of two separate column ranges and calculate variance using Bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I am a beginner trying to work my way around bash scripting with awk, and I have this current problem, with the sample data below:

```
label1  0   0   0   0   0   1
label2  0   0   0   0   0   1
label3  0.2 0.2 0.9 0   0   0
label4  0   0   0.8 0.1 0   0
label5  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.15    0.1 0.1
label6  0.1 0.15    0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

with column 1 being a header of the row, and columns 2 to 7 being numerical values.

I am currently trying to use awk (open to any other suggestions) to output for every new row, in a new file containing 4 columns:

```
label1  0   1   0.166666667
label2  0   1   0.166666667
label3  0.9 0   0.121666667
label4  0.8 0.1 0.103
label5  0.1 0.15    0.000416667
label6  0.15    0.1 0.000416667
```

In which:
column 1 is column 1 from the input
column 2 is maximum value of columns 2 to 4 from the input
column 3 is maximum value of columns 5 to 7 from the input
column 4 is variance of column 2 to 7

Many thanks for your advice and help (and time)!

KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'function max(x,y) {return x>y?x:y}
     function mean(is,ie) {s=0; for(i=is;i<=ie;i++) s+=$i;        return s/(ie-is+1)}
     function var(is,ie,m) {v=0; for(i=is;i<=ie;i++) v+=($i-m)^2; return v/(ie-is)}
  
     {print $1, max(max($2,$3),$4), max(max($5,$6),$7), var(2,7,mean(2,7))}' file | 
column -t

label1  0     1     0.166667
label2  0     1     0.166667
label3  0.9   0     0.121667
label4  0.8   0.1   0.103
label5  0.1   0.15  0.000416667
label6  0.15  0.1   0.000416667
```

**Notes**

> computes "sample variance"
>
> you may want to format the numbers with `printf`
>
> for large scripts you may want to isolate variable names in the functions etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply! I have two questions: 1) in this example, does max always compare only two columns? 2) how would it work to calculate the variance for the sample table I have updated in the question? Thank you very much!

Comment: just change the indices accordingly, see the second max column on how to extend to three elements.